# Azure Static Web App deployment times out unless custom domain is validated

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-static-web-app

I'm trying to deploy an Azure Static Web App with a custom domain using TXT record validation. CNAME validation is not an option as I want to use Cloudflare with CNAME flattening.

The bicep template looks as follows:

```
resource staticWebApp 'Microsoft.Web/staticSites@2021-03-01' = {
  // name, location, tags, sku, properties

  resource examplecomDomain 'customDomains@2021-03-01' = {
    name: 'example.com'
    properties: {
      validationMethod: 'dns-txt-token'
    }
  }
}

output defaultHostname string = staticWebApp.properties.defaultHostname
output validationToken string = staticWebApp::examplecomDomain.properties.validationToken
```

When deploying this, the deployment waits until the domain is validated. But in my pipeline I'd like to use the `validationToken` output to automatically create or update my DNS records using the Cloudflare API.

Is there a way to make the deployment succeed without validating the domain first?
With an Azure App Service, we can deploy it and get the domain verification token before adding a custom domain. But I don't see this option with Azure Static Web Apps.